# Match object position and orientation using Hololens 1 and Optitrack Trio bar

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm currently working on a projet in which we combine a Hololens 1 and the Optitrack Trio bar.
I'm not an expert in 3D so my questions may be trivials but at the moment, i can't find a proper solution so i'm posting here in case someone has already encountered the same issue and has already found a solution.
​​​​
Here is my problem:
The trackbar gives me a 3D base in which objects can be detected (in my case, the Hololens and other objects like a smartphone, physical cubes, etc.). From this, i can get : position (x, y, z), a quaternion (qx, qy, qz, qw) and rotation (yaw, pitch, roll).

When i'm starting my app on the Hololens, the unity 3D base is initialized : (0, 0, 0) is at the hololens position and yaw/roll depends on my initial orientation (pitch is not included as the Hololens Up vector depends on gravity, not on initial rotation).

The Optitrack 3d base is right-handed and unity is left-handed.

My goal is to find the position and orientation of the objects detected by Optitrack in Unity.
Something like that:
Inputs : x, y, z, yaw, pitch, roll in Optitrack coordinate system
Some magic calculations
Outputs: x', y', z', yaw', pitch', roll' all in my Unity coordinate system.

Is there an easy way to achieve that?
Do i need a specitic object that i can detect in both spaces to make the transition? If so, how to find the transition from one 3D base to the other based on this object?

What i tried:
I placed an object detected by optitrack at 0, 0, 0, at 0, 0, 1 and another one at -1, 0, 0 (so i had left and front vectors in unity and optitrack coordinates).
Using a cross-product, i had three vectors U, V, W reprensenting the -X, Y and Z axis of my unity space in Optitrack coordinate system.
I then created a matrix as follow : 
Xu Xv Xw
Yu Yv Yw
Zu Zv Zw
I inverted the matrix (which is now called P)
To calculate an object position from optitrack to unity coordinate system i used this:
unity_coord = P * optitrack_coord.
However, this solution does not work (coordinates are completely wrong) and i cant get the new orientation of my object from this.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with Optitrack Trio bars, but from my basic understanding, you seem to be looking for a way to convert between left-handed coordinate system and right-handed coordinate systems. If so, the helper class `NumericsConversionExtensions`  will be helpful for you. Recommend you trying the following code:[Converting between coordinate systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/unity-xrdevice-advanced#converting-between-coordinate-systems)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was one part of the problem and it seems you found a solution.<br>
The second part is how can i change 3D base between my optitrack base and the unity one?
What are the calculations?
Can i do these calculations just by detecting the Hololens or do i need other items to be detected too?